# Replace double quotes that come in pairs

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I'd like to replace double quotes `"` characters which come in pairs. Let me explain what I mean.

```
"Some sentence"
```

Here double quotes should be replaced  because they come in pair.

```
"Some sentence
```

Here should not be replaced - there is no matching pair for the first quote character.

I'd like to replace first quote character with `„`.

```
❯ echo „ |hexdump -C
00000000  e2 80 9e 0a
```

And the second quote character with `”`

```
❯ echo ” |hexdump -C
00000000  e2 80 9d 0a
```

Summing it up, the following:

```
Hi, "how
are you"
```

Should be the following after being replacement is made.

```
Hi, „how
are you”
```

I've come up with the following code, but it fails to work:
`'sed -r s/(\")(.+)(\")/\1\xe2\x80\x9e\3\xe2\x80\x9d/g'`

`" hi "`   gives `"„"”`.

***EDIT***
As requested in the comments, here comes a sample from a file to be modified. Important note: the file is structured - perhaps it may help. The file is always a srt file, i.e. movie subtitle format.

```
104
00:10:25,332 --> 00:10:27,876
Kobieta mówi do drugiej:
"Widzisz to, co ja?"

105
00:10:28,001 --> 00:10:30,904
A tamta: "No to co?
Każdy wygląda tak samo."
```

Comment: Yes, it needs to. I would like to do some replacements in movie subtitles where double quotes may start on one line but end in the next or even further.

Comment: Yes, the file is structured. Some information is here: https://www.ai-media.tv/what-is-an-srt-file-and-how-to-use-one/. However, when possible, a generic solution is most welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -rn ':a;s/"([^"]*)"/„\1”/g;/"/!{p;b;};$p;N;ba'
```

It substitutes all `"xx"` with `„xx”`. If the result contains no more `"` it is printed and we restart with next line. Else we concatenate the next line and we restart. The `$p` is just here to print the last lines if they contain a dangling `"`.

Comment: Perhaps slurping in the whole file with `-z` might work? i.e. `sed -Ez 's/"([^"]*)"/„\1”/g' file`

Comment: @potong For small files yes. Not sure how it scales with large files. Do you know this? I'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression doesn't work because you have three capturing groups: The three sets of `()`.  You are putting the 1st (the first quote) and the 3rd (the last quote) in the output and ignoring the 2nd, which is the part you want to keep.

There's no reason to capture the quotes, since you don't want to inject them into the output.  Only the bit in the middle needs to be captured.

There is also a flaw, the `(.*)` will itself match against a string containing a quote.  So `/"(.*)"/` would match the entire sequence `"one"two"`, with the capture, `(.*)`, matching `one"two`.  Use `[^"]*` to match a sequence of non-quote characters.

Fixing this, and treating the entire text file as one line with -z, which only works if there are no nul characters in the text file, it appears this works:

```
sed -zE 's/"([^"]+)"/„\1“/g'
```

Comment: Will this work with text files (LF terminated)?

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Non-GNU versions of sed might not support -z.